# Use of tags when asking how to apply one languages' techniques to another

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

I'm in the middle of translating several `R` programs into T-SQL. My current SO question is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19031470/create-a-function-with-whole-columns-as-input-and-output). I'm only using `SQL` related tags and wondering whether or not it was "good SO practice" to use `R` tags as well, hoping some `R` developers have already faced such tasks.

I found this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68322/tags-for-questions-asking-for-solution-conversion-from-one-language-to-another) which unfortunately doesn't clarify my doubt nor give an exact view of the community preference in this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use all tags that really apply. If some SQL developer has R on his ignored tags list, you will save his time. And if not, it will make it easier to sort on the SQL list. On R list, it'll be easy to skip basing on SQL tag so you will not hurt anyone.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to see as many relevant tags as possible as it makes filtering and looking for questions much easier, especially when looking for questions to answer.

The key is that all tags have to be **relevant** even if in some cases the combination of tags is unusual.